# Recurrent email from sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-email, microsoft-flow, recurring-events

I am trying to set up a recurrent monthly email from sharepoint list using flow.
I have not been very successful. I have not found much information in regards this topic.
Can anyone help?
Here are the flow conditions:
This email is only a group reminder to update their list entries.

- Trigger: every 15th of every month
- what: email to sharepoint list group

Thanks a million!

Nacho

Comment: sooo, what have you tried? What aspect are you struggling with? if you don't know where to start at all, maybe you want to consult a few of the free tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a scheduled flow and then send an email.

[image]

I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. If your task is more challenging than this, please edit your question and add more detail.

Comment: Dear Teylyn, I did managed to resolve this issue. Many thanks for your support!